# Silverlight - ClientAccessPolicy.xml Syntax

Tags: silverlight, securityexception, clientaccesspolicy.xml

I'm trying to communicate with an Apache web server in a cross-domain way.

I have a clientaccesspolicy.xml file set up on the root of the domain and it is successfully retrieved by the Silverlight client when attempting to make a GET request to a Java servlet that's been set up.

The specifics are something like this:

URL to access: dev.corp.companyname.com/servlets/targetServlet

The clientaccesspolicy.xml file looks like this:

```
<access-policy> 
  <cross-domain-access> 
    <policy> 
      <allow-from http-request-headers ="*"> 
        <domain uri ="http://*" /> 
      </allow-from > 
      <grant-to > 
        <resource path ="servlets/targetServlet" include-subpaths ="false"/> 
      </grant-to> 
    </policy > 
  </cross-domain-access> 
</access-policy>
```

I'm getting the common SecurityException with "Security Error" as it's message. I assume this means that the clientaccesspolicy.xml file is set up correctly.

So here are the questions:
Should

```
<domain uri ="http://*" />
```

be

```
<domain uri ="*" />
```

Also. Should

```
<resource path ="servlets/targetServlet" include-subpaths ="false"/>
```

be

```
<resource path ="/servlets/targetServlet" include-subpaths ="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `<domain uri ="*" />` if you want to enable all http and https callers. `<domain uri ="http://*" />` will only enable all http callers.

Use `<resource path ="/servlets/targetServlet" include-subpaths ="false"/>` to define a path from the root of the site with no access to any sub directories. Use this to be specific and not releative. From [Network Security Access Restrictions in Silverlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645032%28VS.95%29.aspx)

> The attribute is the URI relative to
>   root of the domain. It refers to a
>   specific path that can represent a web
>   service or a file.
>
> The path cannot contain wildcard
>   characters or characters not
>   recognized by Uniform Resource
>   Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax,
>   http://ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986
>
> This element and attribute are used
>   solely for requests from WebClient and
>   HTTP classes.